# Is it possible to use Hugo in Google Sites?

Tags: web-hosting, google-sites

I want to deploy a [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) template in Google Sites (a free hosting). I currently have a website but I am using the default (new) Google style (I don't link it here because I don't want to reveal my email address).

It is clearly possible to get different styles in Google Sites. Examples of different styles are [here](https://sites.google.com/site/arabevivo/), [here](http://www.slugsps.com/) (this one using the Classic version of Google Sites), and a long list [here](https://www.sitebuilderreport.com/google-sites-examples). But the latter site says:

> If you decide to use Google Sites, you should know that it only includes one template with several style options (called "Themes" in Google Sites).

And yet, there are companies offering template services for Google Sites (e.g. [here](https://www.steegle.com/google-sites/templates)).

I've searched the Hugo documentation and it [only mentions](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hugo-deploy/#google-cloud-storage-gcs) deploying Hugo in Google Cloud Services, which is a [paid service](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website). So, it seems I cannot do what I want for free. is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Huge can be host anywhere which support to host static files. But Google sites is completely different thing, it is **pre built web app/software, not a complete hosting server.** it comes with their own rules, to provide a security. It's same like blogspot, they allowed to write free blog post, but they have their own rules. It's not flexible and you can't do whatever you want, because it's a software/app, it is already program to do only specific things, so it's not in your full control.

Hugo generate static files, so as I said it can be host anywhere who provide hosting service, and there are already free option available like github pages and firebase. [They have already written detail articles on both of them here.](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/) I've used both of them(I'm using jekyll which is built on ruby while hugo is built on Go language, both offer same thing with different lang & features), both hosting server are really great and free and satisfy my most of needs.

Comment: Thanks. So should we conclude it is not possible to use Hugo on Google Sites?

Comment: Correct.  Google sites has its own template system.  It doesn't allow you to work outside its own system at all. You can upload files.  You can't edit the HTML code.  You can't include JavaScript.   You don't even have a ton of control over the URLs for your pages.